# How to check if a returned object is empty or populated in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I am working on a Sample Quiz application. So my code using Web Api's in C# makes a called to the database and gets a quiz that matches the id that was passed. And the data is returned in a JSON format.

If a quiz matching the id is found, this is the data that is passed:

```
{"Id":2,"Options":[{"id":1,"qid":2,"option":"50 mi/hr","result":false},{"id":2,"qid":2,"option":"756 mi/hr","result":false},{"id":3,"qid":2,"option":"765 mi/hr","result":true},{"id":4,"qid":2,"option":"630 mi/hr","result":false}],"Question":"What is the speed of sound through air "}

Quiz: id, Options[],Question.
```

If a quiz is not found, it returns an empty output:

```
{"Id":0,"Options":[],"Question":null}
```

Now in AngularJS, I am trying to check if what is returned is equal to the empty output. This is the code i wrote, but its not working:

```
SimpleQuiz.factory('Quiz', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/Quiz/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } 
});

$scope.startQuiz = function ()
{
    // and id is passed into the Quiz.get function
    // and the returned output is stored in $scope.item
    $scope.item = Quiz.get({ id: $scope.quizid });

    var sampleitem = $scope.item

    // this is the part that isn't working
    if (angular.equals(smpleitem,emptyQuizObject))
    {
        // redirect if they are the same
        $location.path('/start');
    }
    else
    {
        // output to the screen
        $scope.item = $scope.item; // this works
    }
}// end start quiz

var emptyQuizObject = {"Id": 0, "Options": [], "Question": null };
$scope.startQuiz(); // start the quiz
```

C# code for the Web Api:

```
public class QuizController : ApiController
{
    public QuizQuestion Get(int id)
    {
        QuizQuestion question = Models.DbStoredProcModel.GetQuiz.GetaQuiz(id);
        return question;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how Quiz.get is implemented?

Comment: You need to return empty response with 404 code if quiz is not found and then check for it.

Comment: In the line `if (angular.equals(smpleitem,emptyQuizObject))` you have a typo - `smpleitem` should be `sampleitem`